# Rails ActiveRecord query syntax issue - not returning any records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am rewriting a query to make more  readable. Originally, it was all in one line:

```
@properties = Listing.where(website_approved__c: 'true').where(status__c: 'Active').where("sales_price__c >= ?", @pricemin ).where("sales_price__c <= ?", @pricemax ).where(bedrooms__c: @beds ).where(baths__c: @baths ).where("lower(city__c) LIKE (?)", "%" + @city.downcase + "%").where("zip_code__c LIKE (?)", "%" + @zip + "%").page(params[:page]).per(4)
```

I want to split this over multiple lines and I followed a past StackOverflow answer on splitting Ruby code into multiple lines: [Ruby code beautification, split long instructions on multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359948/ruby-code-beautification-split-long-instructions-on-multiple-lines)

This is what I wrote:

```
@properties = Listing.where(website_approved__c: 'true', status__c: 'Active', bedrooms__c: @beds, baths__c: @baths).
    where([ "sales_price__c >= ? AND sales_price__c <= ?", @pricemin, @pricemax]).
    where(["lower(city__c) LIKE (?) AND zip_code__c LIKE (?)", "%"+@city.downcase+"%", "%"+@zip+"%"]).
    page(params[:page]).per(4)
```

However, the new query will never return anything. I kept the WHERE clauses the same, which is why I'm wondering if it's a syntax issue. Can anyone shed some light?

I am currently running Rails v4.2.1.

Comment: If you append `.to_sql` to each version of this query, what do you see? How do the queries differ?

Comment: The second query contains also the `where` condition: `listing_agent__c: @userId` which is not present in the first query...

Comment: Also for general beautification, there are several good reasons to limit yourself to 80 characters per line. This isn't just about how the code looks -- this kind of discipline is a good teacher. It will illuminate places where your code is too complex, too deeply nested, and so on.

Comment: @BoraMa Sorry, I accidentally copy and pasted from another source. Fixed the original question.

Comment: Now the queries seem equivalent to me, to prove, I'd also compare their `to_sql` versions as @CarlTashian suggested above.

Comment: @CarlTashian Thanks for the suggestion. I actually tried removing the square brackets in the second and third where clauses and it ran perfectly. Something about those it doesn't like...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you already fixed your problem.

Since you aimed for better readability I would like to present how I would structure that query (if I wasn't allowed to use scopes):

```
@properties = Listing.where(
  baths__c:            @baths,
  bedrooms__c:         @beds,
  sales_price__c:      (@pricemin..@pricemax),
  status__c:           'Active', 
  website_approved__c: 'true'
).where(
  'lower(city__c) LIKE :city AND zip_code__c LIKE :zip', 
  city: "%#{@city.downcase}%", 
  zip:  "%#{@zip}%"
).page(params[:page]).per(4)
```